# How to Sync Two Different Databases with Millions of Rows and Different Column Structure

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql

I have some problem with database **synchronization** between **two different database** (one is Oracle, the other one is Postgresql), those two database are located in **two different locations** (i.e. two different physical locations or geo-locations), and average internet speed would be around **1Mb/s**.

Here is the problem, let say i have following tables:

1. tableORC inside Oracle DB (this table contains literally **millions** of rows), and
2. tablePG inside Postgresql DB (this table contains literally **hundred of thousands** of rows)

Those two tables (inside different database) will have **different column structure**, here are the structures of those tables:

**tableORC**:

```
+-----------------+-------------+--+--+--+
| serial_26_chars | description |  |  |  |
+-----------------+-------------+--+--+--+
|                 |             |  |  |  |
+-----------------+-------------+--+--+--+
```

**tablePG**:

```
+----+------+--+--+--+
| id | desc |  |  |  |
+----+------+--+--+--+
|    |      |  |  |  |
+----+------+--+--+--+
```

`tableORC` will always get `time-series` change, from many applications/API, i.e. almost every second there would be CRUD operation on `tableORC`, my goal is to keep `tablePG` always in sync with `tableORC`, i.e.:

1. If one `serial_26_chars` row initially present but then got **deleted**, then `id` with same value with `serial_26_chars` will get deleted from `tablePG` too.
2. If `description` on a row got **updated**, then `desc` of corresponding `id` will get updated from `tablePG` too.
3. If one `serial_26_chars` row initially got newly **created**, then `id` with same value with `serial_26_chars` will get newly created on `tablePG` too.

and consider that in one second there are literally **thousands** of CRUD operation on `tableORC` and I want that synchronization with `tablePG` happen in a matter of second across internet (different server location).

For your information, `tableORC` were hosted on **enterprise grade server**, while `tablePG` were hosted on **consumer grade** standard desktop pc.

So how to solve this problem? can you suggest me some method to approach this kind of problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I know you can set up triggers on the oracle server to push the data to the postgres server using ODBC, although I've never used it myself. Performance will be limited by your connection, though; You could also have an aditional table in the oracle server to store each operation made in that table, which will make it easier to find deletes and updates.

Comment: You could try http://www.symmetricds.org/

Comment: I would use an oracle_fdw foreign table in PostgreSQL. That way queries and data modifications on the PostgreSQL table will be redirected towards Oracle, no data are held in PostgreSQL, and the tables are always perfectly synchronized. You can use a view in PostgreSQL if you only want to see part of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement a web services in the postgres server for update changes.

First Option: for each operation from oracle server
Second Option: once a day consult the redo log changes in the oracle server.

You can use something like Pentaho Data Integration in the oracle server for consult the data.